# Proper indexing and sorting with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have a relatively complex query that I'm running.  I've included it below, but essentially I have a location query combined with an $or and $in query all to be sorted by date/time.  Whenever I run the full query though it returns in ascending order rather than descending.

If I pull out the location part of the query, it successfully returns the results in the proper order, but once I put the location component of the query back in, it continues to fail.

Here's the query as written in php:

```
$query = array( 
        '$or' => array(
            array( ISPUBLIC => true ), 
            array( GROUP_INVITES.".".TO.".".INVITE_VAL => array( '$in' => $user_groups ) )
        ),
        LOC => array( '$near' => array( (float)$lon , (float)$lat ), '$maxDistance' => 1 )  //Using 1 degree for the max distance for now
    );

$res = $this->db->find( $query )->sort(array('ts'=>-1))->limit($limit)->skip($start);
```

The fields used are constants that map to fields in the database.  My first assumption was that the indexes are not configured properly, but how should I have this indexed when combining geospatial queries with others?

**UPDATE**

I've been able to replicate the problem by simplifying the query down to:

```
$query = array( 
    HOLLER_GROUP_INVITES.".".HOLLER_TO.".".INVITE_VAL => array( '$in' => $user_groups ),
    HOLLER_LOC => array( '$near' => array( (float)$lon , (float)$lat ), '$maxDistance' => 1 )
);
```

***UPDATE 2***

I've run additional tests and it appears that when limit is removed it's sorted in the correct direction.  No idea what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question appears to have the answer: [Sorting MongoDB GeoNear results by something other than distance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503562/sorting-mongodb-geonear-results-by-something-other-than-distance)  .... apparently $near was already performing a sort.  If you simply want to limit within a given boundary but sort by something else, you should use $within instead of $near.